# Django Rest pass variable not in model for logic in overridden save method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF how can I pass for example a boolean which isn't in my model from ModelViewSet so it can be used in a overridden save method for some logic? I know with a model instance you can just assign it, but I'm unsure if this is possible from ModelViewSet or goes against the general flow of DRF.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask a clear and well-received question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in serializer which includes this model, add one serializer field and add inside class Meta.

```
bool_field = serializer.BoolField()
class Meta:
model = MyModel
fields=['bool_field','MyModel_fields1','mymodelField2']
```